# Two simultaneous mouse listeners disrupting each other in Swing

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

My question concerns how to handle with simultaneous mouse events with Swing.

Both a MouseMotionListener and a MouseListener are added to follow a JPanel.

I have an object whose rotation takes places according to the x and y coordinates of the mouse pointers location (implemented by mouseMoved method of MouseMotionListener).

I've also got a MouseListener that performs its actions according to implemented mouseReleased() method.

The object is rotating neatly according to MouseMotionListener but a problem arises when the mouse button is pressed. As the mouse is now moved the rotation stops as obviously the JPanel is now waiting the mouseReleased() method to be executed.

Any ideas what's the best way to make these events happen simultaneously so that both the rotation according to the mouse pointers coordinates and operations according to mouseReleased() can be performed concurrently without disrupting each other?

Comment: Posting your code would help diagnose the problem. However, the `mouseReleased` method would not execute until you released the mouse button.  The `JPanel` does not wait for you to release the button. Are you doing anything with the `mousePressed` method?

Comment: mousePressed is just overridden, however in the future I have to add some functioning to it also. this is why I'd need to add some concurrency to deal with the task

Comment: Maybe you should not have the rotation when the mouse is simply (no button pressed) in the JPanel, but only when one of the mouse button is held down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An old article going into swing threading specifics:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2007/jw-08-swingthreading.html?page=1

Worth a read as to the whys and hows.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do two action in your application simultaneously, you will do it in diffrent threads
When you need to do something in diffrent threads in swing - you should use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)